# Not showing the path in KML

Tags: google-maps-api-3, kml, patch

I'm trying to create a map of Stockholm subway on Google maps.
I have created a KML file to the blue line http://tourist-sweden.se/transport/map/sthlm/t-11-bana.kml
I call this file with this JavaScript code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Map of Stockholm's subway: line Nr.T-11 "Akalla - Kungstr&#228;dg&#229;rden"</title>
    <link href="https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
function initialize() {
  var subwayblue = new google.maps.LatLng(18.032405,59.334372);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 10,
    center: subwayblue,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'http://tourist-sweden.se/transport/map/sthlm/t-11-bana.kml'
  });
  ctaLayer.setMap(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

But not showing the path between the stations. What is my fault?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your polyline doesn't have a valid color:

http://feedvalidator.org/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Ftourist-sweden.se%2Ftransport%2Fmap%2Fsthlm%2Ft-11-bana.kml