# KMZ do not show of my icons

Tags: kml, kmz

Earlier, I tried to put the file on the host kml. My question here [Not showing the path in KML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17477406/not-showing-the-path-in-kml). Now I created new file kmz on the recommendations of Google. File here: http://tourist-sweden.se/transport/map/sthlm/t-11-1.kmz . Calling map: http://tourist-sweden.se/transport/map/sthlm/t-11-bana.html
Now maps show only the path but do not show of my icons. What a mistake again in my maps? Are there any robust and simple alternative to kml?

Comment: How did you create that KMZ file?  It doesn't seem to work in Google Earth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your KMZ file is not correct.  If you zip up the t-11 directory, it works:

It currently looks like this:

```
[lross@JJ kmz]$ unzip -l t-11-1.kmz
Archive:  t-11-1.kmz
  Length     Date   Time    Name
 --------    ----   ----    ----
        0  07-07-13 12:06   t-11/
     3655  07-07-13 12:43   t-11/t-11-bana.kml
        0  07-07-13 12:08   t-11/files/
     1039  07-04-13 21:21   t-11/files/subway-blue.png
```

If you create it from the t-11 directory so it looks like this, it works:

```
[lross@JJ t-11]$ unzip -l t-11-1a.kmz
Archive:  t-11-1a.kmz
  Length     Date   Time    Name
 --------    ----   ----    ----
        0  07-07-13 12:08   files/
     3655  07-07-13 12:43   t-11-bana.kml
     1039  07-04-13 21:21   files/subway-blue.png
```

http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kmz/t-11-1a.kmz

Comment: My link to KMZ File [link](http://tourist-sweden.se/transport/map/sthlm/t-11-bana.html). Please show me my mistakes and how to correct them. Sorry, but KML was quite difficult for me even though I have good experience in XML.

Comment: KML is XML.  KMZ is KML that has been zipped.  Please see the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmzarchives) (my answer explains the problem, if you have questions on it, please be more specific)